# Flush CSS box alignment

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am practicing CSS with Masonry. I'm doing a bit of basic testing and seeing how everything gets displayed. However I am not sure how to fix this problem. I want to fit all of my pictures inside the `.masonry` class in my CSS but there is this little bit of space that occurs and I'm not sure how to fix it. I want all the boxes to be flush and no white space to be displayed between each box.

Here is the codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Cpedg

[image]

my CSS:

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

body { font-family: sans-serif; }

.masonry{
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #EEE;
  max-width: 80%;
}

.masonry .item,
.masonry .grid-sizer {
  width:  20%;      /*item default width of 20%*/
  margin: 0px;
}

.masonry .item,
.masonry .grid-sizer {
  height: 60px;    /* default hieght of image*/
  float:  left;

  background: #D26;
  border: 1px solid #343;
  border-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.item.w2 { width:  40%; }           /* changes each item to these chracteristics*/

.item.h2 { height: 100px; }
.item.h3 { height: 130px; }
.item.h4 { height: 180px; }
```

my HTML:

```
<h1>Masonry - columnWidth</h1>
<div class="masonry js-masonry"  data-masonry-options='{ "columnWidth": ".grid-sizer", "itemSelector": ".item" }'>
  <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item w2 h2"></div>
  <div class="item h3"></div>
  <div class="item h2"></div>
  <div class="item w3"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item h2"></div>
  <div class="item w2 h3"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item h2"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item w2 h2"></div>
  <div class="item w2"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item h2"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item h3"></div>
  <div class="item h2"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item h2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Definitely going to need a codepen/jsfiddle for this puppy.

Comment: sorry I should have figured. I'll do that right away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove those spaces *between* the cells by adding (or rather removing) margin and padding to (from) your body, like so:

```
body {
    font-family: sans-serif; 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

That's a possible solution for the upper left arrow, but I'm not quite sure what the problem with the second arrow is?

Comment: It may be hard to see but the 2nd arrow is pointing to the block in `.masonry` class if you change the background color from `#EEE` to something different it is easier to see

Comment: change #EEE to #b6ff00 and youll see what I am pointing at. I tried your changes and it didnt really fix anything but thank you for the effort! much appreciated!

Comment: Now I get it. Seems like there's a browser issue, as you have mentioned. For me however, it works just fine. The cell's widths realign after the browser zoom/window size is changed.

Answer (score -1):

So it turns out google chrome's zoom acts a bit funky sometimes. quick fix to realign everything is to press `ctrl + 0` to realign everything!